# Revoke option used on first user after using with grant option

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Im working on Oracle Database 11g:
If user A gives the following privileges to user B on a table 'emp' using:
`Grant select on emp to userB WITH GRANT OPTION;`

User B gives the same to user C using:
`Grant select on emp to userC WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Once this happens, user A uses this:
`Revoke select on emp from userB;`

What is the outcome of the following?
Im a bit confused on this.

Comment: `Grant select on emp to userC WITH GRANT OPTION;` is different from `Grant select on userA.emp to userC WITH GRANT OPTION;` .  I presume your question is actually asking about the second command.

Answer (score 2):

As long as user B has been granted to "select on emp ... WITH GRANT OPTION" he may forward this privilege to somebody else. If the privilege is revoked he cannot do this anymore. (neither select table emp nor grant select to sombody else)

Take a simpler example: `GRANT CREATE TABLE to USER_A`. As long as USER_A has this privilege he can create a new tables. If the privilege is revoked he cannot do this anymore. In this case the table he created before will **not** be dropped, of course. The table stays as it is.
The same applies for `SELECT` privileges.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog](http://uralural.blogspot.com.eg/2011/06/with-grant-option-and-cascading-revoke.html), the `select` privilege will automatically be revoked from `userB` **and** `userC`. This will cascade to any other user who were granted this previlige from `userB` or any of its grantees.